# Kotlin: Fragments used for navigation drawer supportFragmentManager not be able to replace layout as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-drawer

This is the code of MainActivity.kt and i am using navigation drawer in this application

```
fun displayScreen(id: Int) {

    val fragment = when (id) {

        R.id.nav_home -> {

            HomeFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_favourite -> {

            FavouriteFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_About -> {
            AboutFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_Feedback -> {
            FeedbackFragment()
        }
        else -> {
            HomeFragment()
        }

    }
```

> Till now the code is working fine. I think

```
     supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.r1, 
      fragment).commit()
```

> After the layout get replaced the Objects automatically moved to top left 
>         corner

```
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            displayScreen(item.itemId)
            supportActionBar?.setTitle("Home")
        }
        R.id.nav_favourite -> {
            displayScreen(item.itemId)
            supportActionBar?.setTitle("Favourite")
        }
        R.id.nav_About -> {
            displayScreen(item.itemId)
            supportActionBar?.setTitle("About")
        }
        R.id.nav_Feedback -> {
            displayScreen(item.itemId)
            supportActionBar?.setTitle("Feedback")
        }

    }
    displayScreen(item.itemId)


    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

> Expected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mzKy.jpg)

> Getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM3HE.png)

> content_main

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/r1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.example.shikh.kotlinnavigationdrawer.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

> fragment_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: please check the layout files @BhuvaneshBS

Comment: You are not using constraint layout then why you are using constraint attributes

Comment: I removed it still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the `constraint` attributes.

2) Change your activity's layout to `FrameLayout`.

3) Remove the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`part since it is not inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.